# java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (3), reason: RC: 55 The specified network resource or device is no longer available

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jax-ws, websphere-8

I am getting below error on WAS 8.5 when a soap web service (with SSL security) is called.

```
[04/01/20 00:32:11:310 CET] 00000078 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause xyz-client: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsSoapFaultException: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (3), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.
; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (3), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4198)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2208)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1030)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
Caused by: org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsSoapFaultException: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (3), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.
; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (3), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:503)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.invoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:487)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.findNetworkPlan(Unknown Source)
    at xyz.TestController.handleRequestInternal(TestController.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (3), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1363)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1089)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.java:417)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:626)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:566)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:432)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.findNetworkPlan(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:500)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (3), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.<init>(AsyncLibrary.java:924)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.get(AsyncLibrary.java:937)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary.getIOException(AsyncLibrary.java:951)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:705)
    ... 2 more
```

I am using spring JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean for client implementation.
A customized SSLSocketFactory loaded with Key Store and Trust Store has been configures to customProperties.

The code is working when tested from JUnit. The issue is only on WAS server.

Any suggestions would be great.